# How do I implement the following type of search :

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, search

I have to come up with the design  for a search . The searched data is not of document type . The data entity to be searched are medical procedures  basically consists of one/two/three words each . The words are pre defined by the admin . Ex: Angioplasty Surgery , Rhinoplasty , Adrenal Surgery , ACTH simulation test etc .

The end user selects the procedure name from a selection and the user's selection is stored in db . End user refers to a user who is creating his profile .

I index the keywords in a separate table with the user id's . So for Rhinoplasty if three user's have added it , I will have three entries in the indexed table . Similarly for other procedures .

```
Procedure Name |  User ID| 
-------------------------
Rhinoplasty       1
Rhinoplasty       2
Rhinoplasty       3
Adrenal Surgery   2
Adrenal Surgery   3
Angioplasty       1

And so on .
```

The problem arises when some  user tries to search for procedures(which leads him to the profiles)  .He may write 'adrenal surgery' as 'surgery adrenal' or 'angioplasty' as 'angioplasty surgery' or 'ACTH simulation test ' as 'Simulation test for ACTH' . Some times procedures can have synonmys/acronyms as well .

I understand the concept of stop words . I can define common words such as 'surgery' and 'test' under them . Strip my indexed tables of these stop words and strip the search query as well .

How can I implement synonyms ? ALso is there a better way to implement search like this ? I don't think I can look at lucene or solr as they are full text search engines  .

Comment: why dont you add tags for each procedure ? for example for ACTH, the tags can be ACTH, simulation, test .. and you can add the synonyms for each procedure as a tag

Comment: You wrote, that procedure names are predefined and there are about 1000 of these. Can't you use say two-step selection (30x30) instead of search - user selects group of related procedures and then specific one from that group? (I know that this doesn't answer your question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like that you need some kind of full text search solution, take a look at [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or a little less heavyweight [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

For fuzzy match alone, you can try using your database system's built in fulltext indexes too, both [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) and [progresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html) features one. Postgres supports dictionaries for synonyms too.

Comment: I am unaware of fuzzy match . Is this to be used for synonyms ? Also solr , isn't it for document based search ? What I have on hand are fixed names .

Comment: Fuzzy match means just that you can specify `term0 term1` and it still matches if your content is `term1 term0`. Solr can index anything you want, but certainly a heavyweight solution, have to export your data into it and such.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using using like clause in your query
 SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE Procedure Name like "%Surgery Adrenal%";
```

Comment: That will not work ,think of a 1000 such procedure names . Without using at least stop words the above will provide a lot of matches . Alredy tried this approach . Thanks for the reply anyways .